# How to use React hook to update state after completing a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to retrieve article data from my backend api using a fetch request and display it on screen. The request retrieves the data successfully, however when I try to update the state of the component variables using the setArticle hook, nothing happens and the request completes without passing any data in.

```
function Home(props) {

    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {       
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/articles/`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            if (result.error) {
                console.log('Error:', result.error);
                return false;
            }
            console.log(result);
            setArticles(result);
            console.log(articles);
        })
    }, [])

    const articleList = articles.map((article) =>
        <ArticleCard article={article} width='400'/>
    )

    return(
        <ul className="article-list">
            {articleList}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

I've already read the React documentation at https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value and hooks are still incredibly confusing. I understand that the state does not update, but this example takes place outside of a fetch request so the new variable is stored. How am I supposed to get the articles variable to update or return the new variable so that I can map the json data to the articleList?

Comment: How do you know that the state is not updated? There is nothing in your return of your Home component

Comment: That's just commented out code, the real return has an html element with articleList like so: return(<ul className="article-list">
                        {articleList}
                    </ul>)

Comment: What is the structure of `result`? I'm asking because you are checking for an error like so `result.error` (i.e. result is not an array) but then you do `setArticles(result);` assuming that `result` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function Home() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  const FetchArticle = async () => {
    await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          console.log("Error:", result.error);
          return false;
        }
        console.log(result);
        setArticles(result);
        // console.log(articles);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    FetchArticle();
  }, []);

  return (
    // return page HTML and articleList
    <>
      {articles.map((article) => (
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Try this , your code is working fine. I used dummy data and the data can be easily rendered on the screen.

Comment: I am still running into this error on a different class now. This code worked before but now when trying to retrieve a user following the same structure I'm getting an error that the user is undefined.

Comment: It looks like the fetch request isn't going out at all in the network tab. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: @theletterj if you are using async function inside useEffect its doesn't work i think. Try to make a fetch request outside the useEffect and call that fetch request function inside the useEffect. If that still does not work share the updated code of yours

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It would be much better if you'll use redux with redux-thunk here.

redux is a smart-storage, redux-thunk is middleware for making requests like that fetch you have.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).